# php script between reactive form and sql database

Tags: php, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have created a reactive form in my angular app and am trying to submit it to my sql database. I am getting the following error though:

[Error] Origin http://localhost:8100 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

My php script has the following at the top before the code to submit data to the database:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*');    
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS');
```

The function I call in the page.ts file is:

```
this.http.post('https://www.website/../../app-registrationForm.php',    
formData).subscribe(
  (response) => console.log(response),
  (error) => console.log(error)
 )}
```

Do I need to include anything else in the php file to allow access to the php script? If you need any other code happy to provide. Many thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you tried it with a space: `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");`?

Comment: Just to double check (it isn't 100% clear in the question), is it in the `app-registrationForm.php` file you added those headers? And do you call them in the beginning of the file, before you've outputted anything?

Comment: thanks, yes have tried it with a space : *' and unfortunately same error.

Comment: yes Magnus, those are the headers in the app-registrationForm.php file. and yes they are at the start of the php file, have I missed something? thanks